# Learning HTML. How can I remove the ability from clicking on the text?

Tags: html

Every time you click the text, it refreshes the page. It is not supposed to be a hyperlink. It is just supposed to be regular text. I have attached an image and the code below. The navigation link is correct. You are supposed to be able to click on Home, Add Inventory, & View Inventory. But everything else should not be clickable.

[Picture of what I am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zjGOF.png)

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test Run</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container">
            <div id="header">
                <h1>Housing & Residence Life Inventory</h1>
            </div>
            <div id="content">
                <div id="nav">
                    <h3>Navigation</h3>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a class = "selected" href="index.html">Home</li>
                        <li><a href="addinventory.html">Add Inventory</li>
                        <li><a href="">View Inventory</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div id="main">
                    <h2>Home Page</h2>
                    <div id = "homedescription">
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus lobortis mauris et lorem vestibulum dignissim. Mauris accumsan augue quis vestibulum feugiat. Donec rutrum risus risus, at posuere dolor consequat ac. Ut at nulla in felis iaculis hendrerit. Duis sit amet scelerisque tellus. Morbi et ante eget tortor tempor pulvinar pulvinar non lorem. Proin felis quam, mattis sagittis sem eu, scelerisque laoreet nibh. Nullam rhoncus a nisi id porta. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
                        <p>Sed in dui vel ante fringilla sodales. Quisque eu finibus ipsum. Quisque sollicitudin velit et fringilla ultrices. Nunc feugiat elit vitae mauris blandit, sed varius metus tempor. Maecenas neque dui, viverra vel egestas fermentum, mollis at ante. Vivamus ut dolor sodales, dignissim urna eget, placerat lacus. Morbi rutrum tortor ac diam convallis, non congue sem maximus. Morbi vitae posuere turpis, non vestibulum diam.</p>
                        <p>In ac scelerisque leo. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia curae; Aliquam consequat lacus ac elit dictum, at lacinia nibh interdum. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Maecenas pretium nibh vel sodales tincidunt. Aliquam molestie, quam eleifend dignissim sagittis, nunc lorem pellentesque augue, eu euismod neque libero vitae felis. Mauris vel dui sodales, vehicula lectus vel, vestibulum sapien. Vestibulum vehicula at lectus a viverra. Aliquam semper ac elit mollis vulputate. Sed condimentum quam ac libero luctus, ut sagittis quam faucibus. Fusce eu aliquet tortor. Sed euismod mollis hendrerit. Vivamus pellentesque venenatis tortor quis blandit. Pellentesque non maximus nibh.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="footer">
                Copyright &copy; 2021 Keith Baker
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You don't end your `<a>` tags. All tags need to have an ending. The first link is going on forever

Comment: `<li><a class = "selected" href="index.html">Home</a></li>` You missed **</a>** closing tag (3 times)

Comment: Thank you so much! I did not realize that!

Answer (score 0):

you need a closing tag for your `<a>` tag like this

```html
<li><a class = "selected" href="index.html">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="addinventory.html">Add Inventory</a></li>
<li><a href="">View Inventory</a></li>
```